# Angular 2+ Primeng + dropdown + Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, enums, dropdown, primeng

backend: I have REST API request Body contains  one  enum parameter ExperienceType

[image]

frontend :

```
export enum ExperienceType {
  ENTRY,
  INTERMEDIATE,
  EXPERIENCED,
  EXPERT,
}

export const ExperienceTypeMapping = [
  {value: ExperienceType.ENTRY, type: 'ENTRY'},
  {value: ExperienceType.EXPERIENCED, type: 'EXPERIENCED'},
  {value: ExperienceType.EXPERT, type: 'EXPERT'},
  {value: ExperienceType.INTERMEDIATE, type: 'INTERMEDIATE'}
];
```

when i m make post request its looks like object ( {value: 2 , type: "Entry" } ) and not just String "ENTRY" : 
[image]

get values from form :

```
vacancyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ..........................
    experienceType: ['', [Validators.required]],
    ..........................
  });



this.vacanciesService.createVacancy(this.vacancyForm.value).subscribe() ....
```

**so i want to change request Body from object to string {value: 2 , type: "Entry" }  to -> "Entry"**

Im try following but not works :

```
temp=this.vacancyForm.get('experienceType').get('type'))

this.vacancyForm.controls.experienceType.setValue(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
this.vacanciesService.createVacancy({
    ...this.vacancyForm.value,
    experienceType: this.vacancyForm.get('experienceType').get('type')
}).subscribe()
```

Comment: i m try this already and its this.vacancyForm.get('experienceType').get('type') returns null.

Comment: vacancyForm.get('experienceType')  this returns object but cant touch from this object type property

Comment: If it returns object, then you can do ```this.vacancyForm.get('experienceType').type```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: ```this.vacancyForm.get('experienceType').value.type```? :)